# Mixing relative and absolute sizes in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a question about a problem, of which I originally thought, that it would be fairly simple to solve. But apparently it is not - at least not with only CSS.

This is the basic situation:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="height:90%;width:410px;background:#aaaaaa;">
  <div id="top" style="margin:5px;width:400px;background:#ffffff;">
  </div>
  <div id="content" style="margin:5px;width:400px;background:#ffffff;">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have a wrapper div that fills up 90% of the screen height and two inner divs. The first div "top" contains some varying elements. The second div "content" should fill out the remaining space of the wrapper div.

So far, I haven't found a way to set the div "content" to fill up the remaining space - even if I would know the exact height of the div "top" as I only know the relative height of the wrapper div.

Thus, I would be happy to learn of a method to either the div "content" to fill up the remaining space or how to mix relative and absolute sizes (i.e. height:100%-100px).

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no cross-browser solution to achieve what you're trying with `div` elements and CSS. You can however get the behavior you want with the tried and true method of using a `table` instead.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
height:90%;width:410px;background:#aaaaaa;border-spacing:5px;
}
#wrapper td {
padding:0;vertical-align:top;
}
#top {
background:#ffffff;
}
#content {
height:100%;background:#ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table id="wrapper" role="presentation">
  <tr>
    <td id="top">Top</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="content">Content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

It appears I stirred a nest of hornets with my answer. There seems to be a near-religious following of people who say using tables for layout is bad. In many cases that is absolutely true, however [there are situations where a table will do what CSS cannot](http://www.hotdesign.com/seybold/23snags.html). This is one of those situations, where a CSS alternative is on the horizon, but most browsers do not support it yet. It is up to the site designer to decide whether he wants to have a layout with cross-browser functionality now, or use a pure CSS layout with its limitations that may become easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: Never, EVER use tables for layout.

Comment: Then provide a cross-browser solution to this problem that does not use tables.

Comment: @Feysal - if you really must use a table for the basic cross-browser effect, you could at least mitigate its problems. cellspacing and cellpadding, obsolete in the next version of HTML, certainly can be replaced by CSS, and adding `role="presentation"` to the table element will stop the table being called out as a table in modern screen readers, removing the most damaging effect of using a table for layout.

Comment: Very well. `border-spacing` and `padding` work fine at replacing those table attributes, and adding support for screen readers, while not always necessary, does little harm.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code is really wrong:

- don't use comma's after attributes
- don't use inline CSS, put all CSS in a stylesheet and load the stylesheet in your HTML page
- CSS syntax is: `propertie: value;` example: `width: 10px;` not: `width=10px`

---

To use 100% - 100px you can use [CSS3 calc](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc), but this feature has [less browser support](http://caniuse.com/calc). You can use JS to make a sort of calc function.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I corrected the syntax spelling mistakes (the actual code obviously didn't have them; also it has its own css file, but for a mini example I thought it would be clearer to put them next to the html tags)

Comment: why a -1 on this answer? Did I write an 'egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post'? Or a 'clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect' answer?

Answer (score 0):

There is no cross-browser way to get the content div to fill all available space with CSS, but it is fairly easy to make things look as if it did:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper {
width:400px;height:90%;border-style:none solid;border-color:#aaaaaa;border-width:5px;background:#ffffff;
}
#top {
border-bottom: 5px solid #aaaaaa;
}
#content {
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="top">
    Top
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This should be sufficient for most situations, unless you want to use something like an `onmouseover` handler on the content.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the 'unless' you stated yourself is amont the things you cannot do. Also, you cannot have the border to be transparent to show what is beneath all these divs (a transparent border will only show the div).

Comment: The borders are not transparent, they are set to the same grey tone as the wrapper background in your question, to produce the desired visual effect.

Comment: Yes sure. What I meant was: If I would switch to using a transparant wrapper in my example, your solution wouldn't work anymore.